# What is the closest latin wording for "Work to solve"? Opus solvere?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, grammar-choice

Contextually, it is the idea that work/effort should always be done with the goal of finding the solution to a problem or hurdle.

Google suggests "Opus solvere" and the component words seem to make sense, but I'm worried it has just translated "work" followed by "to solve".

Thank you, sincerely for your help!

Comment: Yes, I think you will be looking for 'Work' as a verb.

Comment: Hmm I'm having trouble understand what this is supposed to mean in English. Could you use it in a natural-sounding sentence?

Answer (score 2):

If "work to solve" means you are giving someone the command "Work, in order to solve (something)", then you could say that as **Labora ut solvas**.
That's if you're talking to one person. If you're talking to more than one person then you would say **Laborate ut solvatis**.

Answer (score -1):

There's a construction with the supine. "Laborare solutu." This means "to work to solve" or, more literally "To work with respect to solving."

Comment: Is this a medieval construction?

Comment: @CMonsour: Yes, I meant, Did it originate in the Middle Ages? I don't think I've ever seen the supine used with a verb in quite this way in classical Latin. Can you point to an example? (Or maybe Nickimite can.)

Comment: This is not correct: (a) the -u form of the supinum is only used with adjectives like "facile visu" and occasionally a few nouns like nefas ("nefas est dictu"), so it should be the "solutum", but (b) the -um form is only used with verbs of movement, so, while "laborare solutum" might be understood, it is not idiomatic Latin.